# How to access database connection in controller using constructor

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to use a constructor to set the database connection in the controller. Currently, I am using `using` keyword for setting up the DB connection in each controller like below.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
            public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
                => options.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection");
     }
}
```

and the controller is

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using static WebApplication1.Models.Model;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class BlogController : Controller
    {

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext ()) {
                db.Add(new Blog { Url = "Hello! How are you" });
                db.SaveChanges();
                return View();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

In this, I want to use the controller constructor to set the DB connectcion. something like this.

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

public BlogController(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
     _db = db;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the context during startup so that it can be injected into the controller

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection")
);
```

And refactor the context to expect the options in its constructor so that the options can be injected into the context as well.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext {

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options) {

    }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```